# Complexity for Binary Search (Insertion) for an ordered list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I understand that binary search cannot be done for an unordered array.
I also understand that the complexity of a binary search in an ordered array is `O(log(n))`.

Can I ask

1. what is the complexity for binary search(insertion) for an
   ordered array? I saw from a textbook, it stated that the complexity
   is `O(n)`. Why isn't it `O(1)` since, it can insert directly, just like
   linear search.
2. Since binary search can't be done in unordered list, why is it
   possible to do insertion, with a complexity of `O(N)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertion into list complexity depends on used data structure:

1. **linear array**

   In this case you need to move all the items from index of inserting by one item so you make room for new inserted item. This is complexity `O(n)`.
2. **linked list**

   In this case you just changing the pointers of prev/next item so this is `O(1)`

Now for the ordered list if you want to use binary search (as you noticed) you can use only array. The bin-search insertion of item `a0` into ordered array `a[n]` means this:

1. **find where to place `a0`**

   This is the bin search part so for example find index `ix` such that:

   ```
   a[ix-1]<=a0 AND a[ix]>a0 // for ascending order
   ```

   This can be done by bin search in `O(log(n))`
2. **insert the item**

   so you need first to move all the items `i>=ix` by one to make place and then place the item:

   ```
   for (int i=n;i>ix;i--) a[i]=a[i-1]; a[ix]=a0; n++;
   ```

   As you can see this is `O(n)`.
3. **put all together**

   so `O(n+log(n)) = O(n)` that is why.

BTW. search on not strictly ordered dataset is possible (although it is not called binary search anymore) see

- [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214)

Comment: Linear array is referring to binary search and linked list is referring to linear search?

Comment: for linked list insertion, isn't it complexity suppose to be O(n)?
since although it's ordered, but it may insert at the last position

Comment: @overflowhow yep you're right but you are mixing insert and search operation they are two separate operations. See answer I reedited to match your question