# Collision detection between 2 "linearly" moving objects in WGS84

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, wgs84

**[Complete re-edit by Spektre] based on comments**

I have two start points and velocity vectors in 3D (WGS84) how would I check if they are colliding in 3D within some specified time?

Sample input:

```
// WGS84 objects positions
const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
double pos0[3]={17.76             *deg,48.780            *deg,6054.0}; // lon[rad],lat[rad],alt[m]
double pos1[3]={17.956532816382374*deg,48.768667387202690*deg,3840.0}; // lon[rad],lat[rad],alt[m]
// WGS84 speeds in [km/h] not in [deg/sec]!!!
double vel0[3]={- 29.346910862289782,  44.526061886823861,0.0}; // [km/h] lon,lat,alt
double vel1[3]={- 44.7              ,-188.0              ,0.0}; // [km/h] lon,lat,alt
```

And here correctly transformed positions into Cartesian (using online convertor linked bellow):

```
double pos0[3]={ 4013988.58505233,1285660.27718040,4779026.13957769 }; // [m]
double pos1[3]={ 4009069.35282446,1299263.86628867,4776529.76526759 }; // [m]
```

And these using my conversion from the linked QA below (difference may be caused by different ellipsoid and or floating point errors):

```
double pos0[3] = { 3998801.90188399, 1280796.05923908, 4793000.78262020 }; // [m]
double pos1[3] = { 3993901.28864493, 1294348.18237911, 4790508.28581325 }; // [m]
double vel0[3] = { 11.6185787807449,  41.1080659685389, 0 }; // [km/h]
double vel1[3] = { 17.8265828114202,-173.3281435179590, 0 }; // [km/h]
```

My question is: **How to detect if the objects will collide and when?**

What I really need is if collision occurs within some specified time like `_min_t`.

Beware the speeds are in `[km/h]` in direction of local `North,East,High/Up` vectors! For more info about converting such speeds into Cartesian coordinates see related:

- [How to convert a spherical velocity coordinates into cartesian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161714/2521214)

To validate/check WGS84 position transformations you can use the following online calculator:

- [online WGS84 to XYZ](http://www.apsalin.com/convert-geodetic-to-cartesian.aspx)

I would like to avoid using mesh, primitives or similar stuff if possible.

---

This is Andre's attempt to solve this (based on my answer but missing the speed transformation) left from the original post:

```
bool collisionDetection()
{
    const double _min_t = 10.0; // min_time
    const double _max_d = 5000; // max_distance
    const double _max_t = 0.001; // max_time
    double dt;
    double x, y, z, d0, d1;

    VectorXYZd posObj1 = WGS84::ToCartesian(m_sPos1);
    VectorXYZd posObj2 = WGS84::ToCartesian(m_sPos2);

    const QList<QVariant> velocity;    
    if (velocity.size() == 3)
    {
        dt = _max_t;
        x = posObj1 .x - posObj2 .x;
        y = posObj1 .y - posObj2 .y;
        z = posObj1 .z - posObj2 .z;
        d0 = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
        x = posObj1 .x - posObj2 .x + (m_sVelAV.x - velocity.at(0).toDouble())*dt;
        y = posObj1 .y - posObj2 .y + (m_sVelAV.y - velocity.at(1).toDouble())*dt;
        z = posObj1 .z - posObj2 .z + (m_sVelAV.z - velocity.at(2).toDouble())*dt;
        d1 = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
        double t = (_max_d - d0)*dt / (d1 - d0);

        if (d0 <= _max_d)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (d0 <= d1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (t < _min_t)
        {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is supposed to be valid Cartesian transformed positions and speeds but transformed wrongly due to wrong order of `x, y, z` parameters. The data above is in correct `lon, lat, alt` and `x, y, z` order this is obviously not:

```
posObject2 = {x=1296200.8297778680 y=4769355.5802477235 z=4022514.8921807557 }
posObject1 = {x=1301865.2949957885 y=4779902.8263504291 z=4015541.3863254949 }
velocity object 2: x = -178, y = -50, z = 8
velocity object 1: x = 0, y = -88, z = 0;
```

Not to mention velocities are still not on Cartesian space ...

**EDIT: NEW TEST CASE**

```
m_sPosAV = {North=48.970020901863471 East=18.038928517158574 Altitude=550.00000000000000 }

m_position = {North=48.996515594886858 East=17.989637729707006 Altitude=550.00000000000000 }

d0 = 4654.6937995573062
d1 = 4648.3896597230259
t = 65.904213878080199
dt = 0.1
velocityPoi = {x=104.92401431817457 y=167.91352303897233 z=0.00000000000000000 }
m_sVelAV = {x=0.00000000000000000 y=0.00000000000000000 z=0.00000000000000000 }
```

**ANOTHER TEST CASE:**

```
    m_sPosAV = {North=49.008020930461598 East=17.920928503349856 Altitude=550.00000000000000 }
    m_position = {North=49.017421151053824 East=17.989399013104570 Altitude=550.00000000000000 }
    d0 = 144495.56021027692
    d1 = 144475.91709961568
    velocityPoi = {x=104.92401431817457 y=167.91352303897233 z=0.00000000000000000 }
    m_sVelAV = {x=0.89000000000000001 y=0.00000000000000000 z=0.

00000000000000000 }

    t = 733.05884538126884
```

**TEST CASE 3 COLLISION TIME IS 0**

```
m_sPosAV = {North=48.745020278145105 East=17.951529239281793 Altitude=4000.0000000000000 }
m_position = {North=48.734919749542570 East=17.943535418223373 Altitude=4000.0000000000000 }

v1 = {61.452929549676597, -58.567847120366054, 8.8118360639107198}
v0 = {0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000}

pos0 = {0.85076109780503417, 0.31331329099350030, 4000.0000000000000}
pos1 = {0.85058481032472799, 0.31317377249621559, 3993.0000000000000}
d1 = 2262.4742373961790
```

**LAST TEST CASE:**

```
p0 = 0x001dc7c4 {3933272.5980855357, 4681348.9804422557, 1864104.1897091190}
p1 = 0x001dc7a4 {3927012.3039519843, 4673002.8791717924, 1856993.0651808924}
dt = 100;
n = 6;
v1 = 0x001dc764 {18.446446996578750, 214.19570794229870, -9.9777430316824578}
v0 = 0x001dc784 {0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000}
const double _max_d = 2500; 
double _max_T = 120;
```

**Final Test Case:**

```
m_sPosAV = {North=49.958099932390311 East=16.958899924978102 Altitude=9000.0000000000000 }
m_position = {North=49.956106045262935 East=16.928683918401916 Altitude=9000.0000000000000 }

p0 = 0x0038c434 {3931578.2438977188, 4678519.9203961492, 1851108.3449359399}
p1 = 0x0038c414 {3933132.4705292359, 4679955.4705412844, 1850478.2954359739}
vel0 = 0x0038c3b4 {0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000, 0.00000000000000000}
vel1 = 0x0038c354 {-55.900000000000006, 185.69999999999999, -8.0000000000000000}
dt = 1;   // [sec] initial time step (accuracy = dt/10^(n-1)
n = 5;        // accuracy loops
```

**FINAL CODE:**

```
const double _max_d = 2500; // max_distance m
    m_Time = 3600.0;
    int i, e, n;
    double t, dt;
    double x, y, z, d0, d1 = 0;
    double p0[3], p1[3], v0[3], v1[3];
    double vel0[3], pos0[3], pos1[3], vel1[3];

    vel0[0] = m_sVelAV.x;
    vel0[1] = m_sVelAV.y;
    vel0[2] = m_sVelAV.z;

    vel1[0] = velocityPoi.x;
    vel1[1] = velocityPoi.y;
    vel1[2] = velocityPoi.z;


    pos0[0] = (m_sPosAV.GetLatitude()*pi) / 180;
    pos0[1] = (m_sPosAV.GetLongitude()*pi) / 180;
    pos0[2] = m_sPosAV.GetAltitude();

    pos1[0] = (poi.Position().GetLatitude()*pi) / 180;
    pos1[1] = (poi.Position().GetLongitude()*pi) / 180;
    pos1[2] = poi.Position().GetAltitude();


    WGS84toXYZ_posvel(p0, v0, pos0, vel0);
    WGS84toXYZ_posvel(p1, v1, pos1, vel1);
    dt = 1;   // [sec] initial time step (accuracy = dt/10^(n-1)
    n = 5;        // accuracy loops
    for (t = 0.0, i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for (e = 1; t <= m_Time; t += dt)
        {
            d0 = d1;
            // d1 = relative distance in time t
            x = p0[0] - p1[0] + (v0[0] - v1[0])*t;
            y = p0[1] - p1[1] + (v0[1] - v1[1])*t;
            z = p0[2] - p1[2] + (v0[2] - v1[2])*t;
            d1 = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
            if (e) { e = 0; continue; }
            // if bigger then last step stop (and search with 10x smaller time step)
            if (d0<d1) { d1 = d0; t -= dt + dt; dt *= 0.1; if (t<0.0) t = 0.0; break; }
        }
    // handle big distance as no collision
    if (d1 > _max_d) return false;
    if (t >= m_Time) return false;

    qDebug() << "Collision at time t= " << t;
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by vectors colliding? Do you mean that you are given starting points, in addition to the velocity vectors, and you want to know if objects with those starting points and constant velocity vectors will collide in the future? What do you mean by a "bounding sphere": the usual solution method for the problem I outline does not use such a thing. And yes, the time can also be calculated, but first confirm if that is your actual problem. You may also be asking if the paths of the object intersect, without the objects themselves colliding.

Comment: I'm giving a position vector for two objects, and I have their velocity vectors. I would like to know if the objects with those starting points and constant velocity vectors will collide

Comment: That depends a lot on the shape of the objects.

Comment: @NicoSchertler There is no shape of the objects, the objects are just two points with two velocity vectors

Comment: Then it is very unlikely they will ever collide. Just solve `start1 + t v1 = start2 + t v2`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler What If I have two points that are moving using a velocity vector, and I want to check for collisions ?

Comment: @andre you got the answer in last Nico Schertler's comment. solve the linear equation (pick one axis that is not trivial) solve`t` if solution found then the lines intersect. The problem is you would need perpendicular distance between infinite lines ... that is the closest point on the 2 paths if they occur near the same time only then the objects really collide ... so you need to find `t1,t2` such `|start1 + t1.v1  - start2 - t2.v2|<=min_distance`  AND `|t1-t2|<min_time` which is basic math stuff ...

Comment: @andre `v1,v2` are your velocity 3D vectors `start1,start2` are the actual 3D positions and `t1,t2` are searched time scalar parameters. the `min_distance` and `min_time` are search threshold scalar constants which will affect how big area is considered for collision

Comment: @Spektre I was waiting for your answer a long time ago. I know you know about that issues :)

Comment: @Spektre Can you post it as an answer, and show some pseudo code please ?

Comment: @andre your velocity vectors are suspicious there should be also `z` component if they are Cartessian (the probability you are moving parallel to equator is obscure) so it is more likely it is still in spherical coordinates in which the units are even more suspicious nor `[deg/s]` nor `[rad/s]`. In case of Cartessian the speed of obj1 is ~191km/h that is OK but for spherical case maybe some insane angle fraction per hour hard to tell you should check the doc from where you get those ...

Comment: @andre have completely reedited your Question. please do not delete relevant data,... you can replace/correct invalid one and add new one but if you delete the base of your question then how you can expect someone else will answer or even use your question?

Comment: @Spektre The collision works fine now. I found that the position and velocities are in kilometers / h.  Now there is a problem, the time 't' is increasing until it hit min_time. I want it to decrease until it hit the max time. so I predict that a collision will happen in 10 secs from now

Comment: @andre that does not make any sense `t` is not increasing nor decreasing it is the time of collision. If you are animating then yes it is decreasing unless you have screw something up again. Hope you did convert the `km/h` to `m/s` ...

Comment: @andre (wrong conversion have to divide by 3.6 instead of multiply :) ) `t=261sec` have added `edit3` with updated code including speed transformation...

Comment: @Spektre I wish I can vote up for your comments :). I found that double vel1[3]={- 44.7              ,-188.0              ,0.0}; // [km/h] lon,lat,alt
is in m/s now Km/H

Comment: @andre I use SI so everything is in `[m],[m/s]` that is why the input values are multiplied by `kmh=1.0/3.6` see my answer .... in input data it is clearly stated it is km/h not m/s

Comment: I meant for vel1, its in m/s not Kmh but for object 2 its in Kmh

Comment: @andre that is real mess ... may be it would be wise to code the whole thing from scratch if it contains such inconsistencies or you may spend eternity with debugging...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edit5] Complete reedit in case you need old sources see the revision history**

As Nico Schertler pointed out checking for line to line intersection is insanity as the probability of intersecting 2 trajectories at same position and time is almost none (even when including round-off precision overlaps). Instead you should find place on each trajectory that is close enough (to collide) and both objects are there at relatively same time. Another problem is that your trajectories are not linear at all. Yes they can appear linear for shor times in booth WGS84 and Cartesian but with increasing time the trajectory bends around Earth. Also your input values units for speed are making this a bit harder so let me recapitulate normalized values I will be dealing with from now:

1. **Input**

   consists of two objects. For each is known its actual position (in **WGS84** `[rad]`) and actual speeds `[m/s]` but not in Cartesian space but **WGS84** local axises instead. For example something like this:

   ```
   const double kmh=1.0/3.6;
   const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
   const double rad=180.0/M_PI;
   //                      lon            lat      alt
   double pos0[3]={  23.000000*deg, 48.000000*deg,2500.000000 };
   double pos1[3]={  23.000000*deg, 35.000000*deg,2500.000000 };
   double vel0[3]={ 100.000000*kmh,-20.000000*kmh,   0.000000*kmh };
   double vel1[3]={ 100.000000*kmh, 20.000000*kmh,   0.000000*kmh };
   ```

   **Beware mine coordinates are in `Long,Lat,Alt` order/convention !!!**
2. **output**

   You need to compute the time in which the two objects "collide" Additional constrains to solution can be added latter on. As mentioned before we are not searching for intersection but "closest" approach instead that suffice collision conditions (like distance is smaller then some threshold).

After some taught and testing I decided to use iterative approach in **WGS84** space. That brings up some problems like how to convert speed in `[m/s]` in **WGS84** space to `[rad/s]` in **WGS84** space. This ratio is changing with object altitude and latitude. In reality we need to compute angle change in `long` and `lat` axises that are "precisely" equal to `1m` traveled distance and then multiply the velocities by it. This can be approximated by arc-length equation:

```
l = dang.R
```

Where `R` is actual radius of angular movement, `ang` is the angle change and `l` is traveled distance so when `l=1.0` then:

```
dang = 1.0/R
```

If we have Cartesian position `x,y,z` (`z` is Earth rotation axis) then:

```
Rlon = sqrt (x*x + y*y)
Rlat = sqrt (x*x + y*y + z*z)
```

Now we can iterate positions with time which can be used to approximate closest approach time. We need to limit the max time step however so we do not miss to much of the Earth curvature. This limit is dependent on used speeds and target precision. So here the algorithm to find the approach:

1. **init**

   set initial time step to the upper limit like `dt=1000.0` and compute actual positions of booth objects in Cartesian space. From that compute their distance `d1`.
2. **iteration**

   set `d0=d1` then compute actual speeds in **WGS84** for actual positions and add `speed*dt` to each objects actual `WGS84` position. Now just compute actual positions in Cartesian space and compute their distance `d1`

   if `d0>d1` then it menas we are closing to the closest approach so goto **#2** again. 

   In case `d0==d1` the trajectories are parallel so return approach time `t=0.0`

   In case `d0<d1` we already crossed the closest approach so set `dt = -0.1*dt` and if `dt>=desired_accuracy` goto **#2** otherwise stop.
3. **recover best `t`**

   After the iteration in **#2** we should recover the best time back so return `t+10.0*dt;`

Now we have closest approach time `t`. Beware it can be negative (if the objects are going away from each other). Now you can add your constrains like

```
if (d0<_max_d)
 if ((t>=0.0)&&(t<=_max_T))
  return collision ...
```

Here **C++** source for this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <math.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double kmh=1.0/3.6;
const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
const double rad=180.0/M_PI;
const double  _earth_a=6378137.00000;   // [m] WGS84 equator radius
const double  _earth_b=6356752.31414;   // [m] WGS84 epolar radius
const double  _earth_e=8.1819190842622e-2; //  WGS84 eccentricity
const double  _earth_ee=_earth_e*_earth_e;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double _max_d=2500.0;         // [m] collision gap
const double _max_T=3600000.0;      // [s] max collision time
const double _max_dt=1000.0;        // [s] max iteration time step (for preserving accuracy)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                      lon            lat      alt
double pos0[3]={  23.000000*deg, 48.000000*deg,2500.000000 }; // [rad,rad,m]
double pos1[3]={  23.000000*deg, 35.000000*deg,2500.000000 }; // [rad,rad,m]
double vel0[3]={ 100.000000*kmh,-20.000000*kmh,   0.000000*kmh }; // [m/s,m/s,m/s]
double vel1[3]={ 100.000000*kmh,+20.000000*kmh,   0.000000*kmh }; // [m/s,m/s,m/s]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double divide(double x,double y)
        {
        if ((y>=-1e-30)&&(y<=+1e-30)) return 0.0;
        return x/y;
        }
void  vector_copy(double *c,double *a)         { for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=a[i];       }
double vector_len(double *a) { return sqrt((a[0]*a[0])+(a[1]*a[1])+(a[2]*a[2])); }
void  vector_len(double *c,double *a,double l)
        {
        l=divide(l,sqrt((a[0]*a[0])+(a[1]*a[1])+(a[2]*a[2])));
        c[0]=a[0]*l;
        c[1]=a[1]*l;
        c[2]=a[2]*l;
        }
void  vector_sub(double *c,double *a,double *b) { for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=a[i]-b[i]; }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84toXYZ(double *xyz,double *abh)
    {
    double  a,b,h,l,c,s;
    a=abh[0];
    b=abh[1];
    h=abh[2];
    c=cos(b);
    s=sin(b);
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    l=_earth_a/sqrt(1.0-(_earth_ee*s*s));
    xyz[0]=(l+h)*c*cos(a);
    xyz[1]=(l+h)*c*sin(a);
    xyz[2]=(((1.0-_earth_ee)*l)+h)*s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84_m2rad(double &da,double &db,double *abh)
    {
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    double p[3],rr;
    WGS84toXYZ(p,abh);
    rr=(p[0]*p[0])+(p[1]*p[1]);
    da=divide(1.0,sqrt(rr));
    rr+=p[2]*p[2];
    db=divide(1.0,sqrt(rr));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double collision(double *pos0,double *vel0,double *pos1,double *vel1)
    {
    int e,i,n;
    double p0[3],p1[3],q0[3],q1[3],da,db,dt,t,d0,d1,x,y,z;
    vector_copy(p0,pos0);
    vector_copy(p1,pos1);
    // find closest d1[m] approach in time t[sec]
    dt=_max_dt; // [sec] initial time step (accuracy = dt/10^(n-1)
    n=6;        // acuracy loops
    for (t=0.0,i=0;i<n;i++)
     for (e=0;;e=1)
        {
        d0=d1;
        // compute xyz distance
        WGS84toXYZ(q0,p0);
        WGS84toXYZ(q1,p1);
        vector_sub(q0,q0,q1);
        d1=vector_len(q0);
        // nearest approach crossed?
        if (e)
            {
            if (d0<d1){ dt*=-0.1; break; }                  // crossing trajectories
            if (fabs(d0-d1)<=1e-10) { i=n; t=0.0; break; }  // parallel trajectories
            }
        // apply time step
        t+=dt;
        WGS84_m2rad(da,db,p0);
        p0[0]+=vel0[0]*dt*da;
        p0[1]+=vel0[1]*dt*db;
        p0[2]+=vel0[2]*dt;
        WGS84_m2rad(da,db,p1);
        p1[0]+=vel1[0]*dt*da;
        p1[1]+=vel1[1]*dt*db;
        p1[2]+=vel1[2]*dt;
        }
    t+=10.0*dt; // recover original t
//  if ((d0<_max_d)&&(t>=0.0)&&(t<=_max_T)) return collision; else return no_collision;
    return t;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here an overview of example:

[image: overview]

Red is object0 and Green is object1. The White squares represents position at computed collision at time `t_coll [s]` with distance `d_coll [m]`. Yellow squares are positions at user defined time `t_anim [s]`  with distance `d_anim [m]` which is controlled by User for debugging purposes. As you can see this approach works also for times like 36 hours ...

Hope I did not forget to copy something (if yes comment me and I will add it)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130597/discussion-on-answer-by-spektre-checking-collision-if-i-have-two-velocity-vector).

Comment: what is dalt, dlat, dlon, is it the velocity vector of alt,lon, latitude ? or the speed in alt, lon, lat

Comment: @andre speed of coarse in `([rad/s],[rad/s],[m/s])` or  `([deg/s],[deg/s],[m/s])` that should be obvious as it is elementary school physics .... `pos1 = pos0 + vel*time` and `vel=(pos1-pos0)/time` Of coarse if you wan more precise transform you need to use WGS84 instead sphere ....

Comment: I don't have the speed dalt, dlat, lon, at all, I have the velocity vector in these coordinates.

Comment: meter per seconds

Comment: @andre if it is in `[m/s]` then is that in spherical coordinate system? if yes then you need to convert it differently

Comment: yes its in the format of WGS84, how would I convert it. Would you check please the updated code

Comment: @andre find out that your transform is `lat,lon,alt` and not `lon,lat,alt` so are your points `lon,lat,alt` or not? if yes then you are feeding the data into transform in wrong order ... If not then your original data descrption was wrong hence the different results ....

Comment: @Spektre m_sPosAV = {North=89.999999958090484 East=80.477831559478233 Altitude=7306.0200000000004 }
Your function returns wrong result, I used the http://www.apsalin.com/convert-geodetic-to-cartesian.aspx
To verify the result, its incorrect

Comment: @andre argh was looking at wrong variable... If I feed the coordinates in correct order my transform returns `0.000770081333182288, 0.00459091200205796, 6364061.02` which is pretty close (difference is less then 3m) to that link you gave. The difference could be because of `double` precision ...but hard to say which one is better. The problem is that `_earth_a*_earth_a` is really huge number and `float` is not capable of holding it precisely. Even `double` is stretching its limits as it needs `16` digits of info which is really near the double limit and we are doing computations on top of that

Comment: @Spektre Hi. The collision works fine now. The problem is I want to make a sphere out of the object and check for collision. I know the collision between two spheres is done using the check for the total radius. But how would I define a sphere from the cartesian coordinates that its converted from spherical ?

Comment: I also want after doing the bounding sphere collision, to get the time of collision, so I would use the same code above correct ?

Comment: @Spektre Hi, I found that the objects are non linear, how would to solve that problem ?

Comment: @andre hi was of line for some time ... for that you need to specify more info ... what kind of non linearity (equation, constants ... ) otherwise is your question unanswerable .... solution is the same you can either iterate by some small time step or solve system of equations for relative distance so it is smaller then some collision threshold distance ...

Comment: What should I read more about these stuff ? any book recommendation ? The non linearity comes that the ship has different altitude, and different velocity over time, so sometimes its moving in a curve and sometimes it moves in linear line

Comment: @andre I have no idea in English but any Physics and or Dynamics school book covering motion equations should do ... especially D'Lambert and Newtonian motion for non relativistic speeds. You have to write equation for each object as function of time and solve system of these (for each object)  that minimizes the distance in relatively the same time.... (either numerically, algebraically or iteratively)

Comment: @Spektre Hi. Today I tested the collision and it works fine for vertical velocity only. but when both the flight and the ship are in the case that is shown in the figure, the collision time is so big its 700 secs. How would I solve it ?

Comment: @andre I see no relevant figure in your question nor any details about the movements. Your image is just green stuff with some marker which without any additional info adds no information ...

Comment: The blue arrow is the flight, and the other arrow is the ship. You see the flight is going to collide with the ships, but the velocity of the flight is vertical along the y axis. I measured the time and its 700secs. but when the flight is going from down to up and collide with the ship, that works perfect. The grey arrow is the ship that is going to collide with the blue which is the flight. When the ship goes down and the flight goes down too, the time is so big 700secs. The other way around is working perfectly, which the flight moves up and the ship moves downwards

Comment: @andre without knowing the coordinates and speeds is hard to say .... my bet is you screw something up somewhere and the cases that works are just a coincidence ...

Comment: can the collision time be predicted in minutes ? is that possible ? what should I change to make it work in minutes ?  does altitude affect the collision, so that the ship and the flight should have both the same altitude ?

Comment: @andre easily just convert the time in seconds to minutes by dividing by `60` .... for example: `min=floor(t/60.0); sec=t-60.0*min;`

Comment: @andre (missed it before) yes altitude does affect collision because it is incorporated in Cartessian distance. The Altittudes odes not need to be the same but close (in time of collision).

Comment: d1 is not initalized

Comment: @andre it is in the loop ... that is why `e` toggles first pass without comparison as `d0` is not OK yet

Comment: @andre initial setting of `dt` is the time step I called `_max_t` the `_max_T` is time interval where this search for the closest approach ... so if you want another accuracy time step change the `dt=100.0` to what ever just take in mind that accuracy for `dt=100.0,n=6` is `0.001 [sec]` which is enough I think. Also the lower the `dt` is and higher `_max_T` is the more iteration it will need to compute ...

Comment: Yes I know that. But I want to have a min time for the collision. like a min time that collision occurs in 10 secs or 20 secs

Comment: @what shoudl it do exactly?  if you want ignore collisions after that time then it is the `_max_T`  if you want ignore collisions  before that time change the `t=0.0`  to `t=_min_t` and `if (t<0.0) t=0.0;` to `if (t<_min_t) t=_min_t;` instead ... if you want different behavior  you need to describe it first

Comment: I should predict collision for example if there is a collision that will happen in 10 secs from now and on.

Comment: @andre then the `_max_T` is the constant you want to set ... also change `dt` to fraction of it ...  so if `_max_T=10;`  then use for example `dt=1.0; n=5;`

Comment: @andre `t=0`  means either the closest approach is at `t=0` or the objects are going away from each other so the closest approach is at `t<0`  which is not searched ... which one it isi is decided from the `d1` state .... if you want to set `dt` by some equation then do it (it isi mentioned in the code) so for example `dt=precision*10^(n-1)` but should be smaller then `_max_T` so you can add `if` to clamp it ... or use something like `dt=_max_T*0.001` and compute n from accuracy or whatever .... you can also ignore `n` and stop the main loop when `dt<accuracy` instead

Comment: so its not a bug ? The collision works perfectly, thanks a lot and happy new year.

Comment: @andre no it is not bug ... iteration is more accurate as I mentioned before few times already.... but it is slower to compute ... for huge times you can update the spherical position instead and then transform to Cartesian inside the loop to account for the curvature of Earth

Comment: can you explain the iterative approach more, I need to learn more about it, instead of copying and paste the code, if you can you post a figure too. Thanks so much !

Comment: @andre what figure? It just compute distance in times 0,1dt,2dt,3dt... and remember the smallest  after that do it again from nearby time with smaller step to improve accuracy that is all, similar to this [How approximation search works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214) but simpler and less advanced (to make it easier to understand)

Comment: I have added a test case which is not working at all. Thanks a lot spketre and happy new year

Comment: @andre the last case works for me ... closest approach in `39.371s`  distance `1089.631m`  looks like you screwup the conversion to cartesian mine are: `p0={ 3938182.67192947, 1200934.91108298, 4866682.19592028 }` and `p1 = { 3938978.11607673, 1198907.37719864, 4866539.31204547 }` most likely you mixed up the order of operands and or forget to convert `[deg]` to `[rad]` and or still using the old non linear conversion. So DEBUG it first!!!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the full code. it seems its correct, I didn't mix anything up

Comment: @andre if you are using mine `WGS84toXYZ_posvel` then yes you did as mine order of operands is `lon,lat,alt` instead of yours `lat,lon,alt` which I warned you before few times already ...

Comment: @Spektre I noticed a problem. Some objects have d0 <=d1. but the difference is very little, in the precision of 0.1 or 0.01. The two objects are close together, but there is no collision due d0 <d=1. Do you need a test case ? please let me know If you need more information

Comment: @Spektre Thanks so much. Note that I don't need the spherical to Cartesian coordinates, now I get the coordinates of the velocity and the positions in Cartesian coordinates

Comment: @andre You should delete all obsolete comments here it is unreadable mess ... (hit the `x` button  after `edit`)

Answer (score 1):

You do not show any code, so I will just give the main ideas and leave the coding to you. Come back if you try some code and are stuck, but show your effort and your code so far.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. One way is to set parametric equations for each object, giving your two functions in time `t`. Set the results of those functions equal and solve for time. For 3D coordinates that gives you three questions, one for each coordinate, and it is very unlikely that the values of `t` will be the same for all three equations. If they are the same, that is the time of your collision.

Another way, which allows for some floating-point rounding errors, is to change the frame of reference to that of one of the objects. You subtract the two velocity vectors, say `v2-v1`, and you now have the velocity of the second object relative to the first object. Now find the distance from the now-stationary first object to the line of the moving second object. If you don't know how to do that, look up 'distance from point to line' in your favorite search engine. You then see if that distance is small enough for you to consider it as a collision--you are unlikely to get a perfect collision, a zero distance, given floating-point rounding errors. If it is small enough, you then see if that collision is reached in the future or was reached in the past. You may want to find the projection of the point on the line as an intermediate value for that last calculation.

Is that clear?

Comment: I have put the code so far, would you check it please ?

Comment: @andre: My Java (or whatever you used) is not good, and you do not define your methods `Position()` or `GetLongitude() ` or `qDebug()` so I cannot say much.