# How to convert a spherical velocity coordinates into cartesian

Tags: math, vector, 3d, wgs84

I have a velocity vector in altitude, longitude, altitude, I would like to convert it to Cartesian coordinates, vx,vy,vz. The format is from WGS84 standard.

here is the formula

```
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    template <class T> 
    TVectorXYZ<T> WGS84::ToCartesian(T latitude, T longitude, T elevation)
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        double sinlat, coslat;
        double sinlon, coslon;
        sincos_degree(latitude,  sinlat, coslat);
        sincos_degree(longitude, sinlon, coslon);  

        const double v = a / sqrt(1 - WGS84::ee * sinlat*sinlat);

        TVectorXYZ<T> coord
        (
            static_cast<T>((v + elevation) * coslat * sinlon),
            static_cast<T>(((1 - WGS84::ee) * v + elevation) * sinlat),
            static_cast<T>((v + elevation) * coslat * coslon)                                    
        );

        return coord;
    }
```

Comment: I think that this question should be on http://mathoverflow.net/ or something similar

Comment: @IulianPopescu: Definitely not Math Overflow, as that's for *research level* questions. http://math.stackexchange.com/ might work.

Comment: @MvG Is it a hard problem ?

Comment: No, this isn't a hard problem.  The person cited the formula and posted code.  What's the problem?  Is the code wrong?

Comment: Here's how it's done: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK based on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41101107/2521214) and long comment flow lets assume your input is:

```cpp
lon [rad], lat [rad], alt [m] // WGS84 position
vlon [m/s], vlat [m/s], alt [m/s] // speed in WGS84  lon,lat,alt directions but in [m/s]
```

And want output:

```cpp
x,y,z // Cartesian position [m/s]
vx,vy,vz // Cartesian velocity [m/s]
```

And have **valid** transformation to Cartesian coordinates for positions at your disposal this is mine:

```cpp
void WGS84toXYZ(double &x,double &y,double &z,double lon,double lat,double alt) // [rad,rad,m] -> [m,m,m]
    {
    const double  _earth_a=6378137.00000;   // [m] WGS84 equator radius
    const double  _earth_b=6356752.31414;   // [m] WGS84 epolar radius
    const double  _earth_e=8.1819190842622e-2; //  WGS84 eccentricity
    const double _aa=_earth_a*_earth_a;
    const double _ee=_earth_e*_earth_e;
    double  a,b,x,y,z,h,l,c,s;
    a=lon;
    b=lat;
    h=alt;
    c=cos(b);
    s=sin(b);
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    l=_earth_a/sqrt(1.0-(_ee*s*s));
    x=(l+h)*c*cos(a);
    y=(l+h)*c*sin(a);
    z=(((1.0-_ee)*l)+h)*s;
    }
```

And routine for normalize vector to unit size:

```cpp
void normalize(double &x,double &y,double &z)
    {
    double l=sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
    if (l>1e-6) l=1.0/l;
    x*=l; y*=l; z*=l;
    }
```

Yes you can try to derive the formula lihe @MvG suggest but from your rookie mistakes I strongly doubt it would lead to successful result. Instead you can do this:

1. **obtain `lon,lat,alt` direction vectors for your position `(x,y,z)`**

   that is easy just use some small step increment in **WGS84** position convert to Cartesian substract and normalize to unit vectors. Let call these direction basis vectors `U,V,W`.

   ```cpp
   double Ux,Uy,Uz;    // [m]
   double Vx,Vy,Vz;    // [m]
   double Wx,Wy,Wz;    // [m]
   double da=1.567e-7; // [rad] angular step ~ 1.0 m in lon direction
   double dl=1.0;      // [m] altitide step 1.0 m
   WGS84toXYZ( x, y, z,lon   ,lat,alt   ); // actual position
   WGS84toXYZ(Ux,Uy,Uz,lon+da,lat,alt   ); // lon direction Nort
   WGS84toXYZ(Vx,Vy,Vz,lon,lat+da,alt   ); // lat direction East
   WGS84toXYZ(Wx,Wy,Wz,lon,lat   ,alt+dl); // alt direction High/Up
   Ux-=x; Uy-=y; Uz-=z;
   Vx-=x; Vy-=y; Vz-=z;
   Wx-=x; Wy-=y; Wz-=z;
   normalize(Ux,Uy,Uz);
   normalize(Vx,Vy,Vz);
   normalize(Wx,Wy,Wz);
   ```
2. **convert velocity from `lon,lat,alt` to `vx,vy,vz`**

   ```cpp
   vx = vlon*Ux + vlat*Vx + valt*Wx;
   vy = vlon*Uy + vlat*Vy + valt*Wy;
   vz = vlon*Uz + vlat*Vz + valt*Wz;
   ```

Hope it is clear enough. As usual be careful about the units `deg/rad` and `m/ft/km` because units matters a lot.

Btw `U,V,W` basis vectors form [NEH reference frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404784/2521214) and in the same time are the direction derivates **MvG** is mentioning.

**[Edit1] more precise conversions**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- WGS84 transformations ver: 1.00 ---------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _WGS84_h
#define _WGS84_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Ellipsoidal_and_Cartesian_Coordinates_Conversion
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// WGS84(a,b,h) = (long,lat,alt) [rad,rad,m]
// XYZ(x,y,z) [m]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double  _earth_a=6378137.00000;   // [m] WGS84 equator radius
const double  _earth_b=6356752.31414;   // [m] WGS84 epolar radius
const double  _earth_e=8.1819190842622e-2; //  WGS84 eccentricity
//const double  _earth_e=sqrt(1.0-((_earth_b/_earth_a)*(_earth_b/_earth_a)));
const double  _earth_ee=_earth_e*_earth_e;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double kmh=1.0/3.6;               // [km/h] -> [m/s]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XYZtoWGS84       (double *abh                  ,double *xyz                  ); // [m,m,m] -> [rad,rad,m]
void WGS84toXYZ       (double *xyz                  ,double *abh                  ); // [rad,rad,m] -> [m,m,m]
void WGS84toXYZ_posvel(double *xyzpos,double *xyzvel,double *abhpos,double *abhvel); // [rad,rad,m],[m/s,m/s,m/s] -> [m,m,m],[m/s,m/s,m/s]
void WGS84toNEH       (reper &neh                   ,double *abh                  ); // [rad,rad,m] -> NEH [m]
void WGS84_m2rad      (double &da,double &db,double *abh);                           // [rad,rad,m] -> [rad],[rad] representing 1m angle step
void XYZ_interpolate  (double *pt,double *p0,double *p1,double t);                   // [m,m,m] pt = p0 + (p1-p0)*t in ellipsoid space t = <0,1>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XYZtoWGS84(double *abh,double *xyz)
    {
    int i;
    double  a,b,h,l,n,db,s;
    a=atanxy(xyz[0],xyz[1]);
    l=sqrt((xyz[0]*xyz[0])+(xyz[1]*xyz[1]));
    // estimate lat
    b=atanxy((1.0-_earth_ee)*l,xyz[2]);
    // iterate to improve accuracy
    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
        s=sin(b); db=b;
        n=divide(_earth_a,sqrt(1.0-(_earth_ee*s*s)));
        h=divide(l,cos(b))-n;
        b=atanxy((1.0-divide(_earth_ee*n,n+h))*l,xyz[2]);
        db=fabs(db-b);
        if (db<1e-12) break;
        }
    if (b>0.5*pi) b-=pi2;
    abh[0]=a;
    abh[1]=b;
    abh[2]=h;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84toXYZ(double *xyz,double *abh)
    {
    double  a,b,h,l,c,s;
    a=abh[0];
    b=abh[1];
    h=abh[2];
    c=cos(b);
    s=sin(b);
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    l=_earth_a/sqrt(1.0-(_earth_ee*s*s));
    xyz[0]=(l+h)*c*cos(a);
    xyz[1]=(l+h)*c*sin(a);
    xyz[2]=(((1.0-_earth_ee)*l)+h)*s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84toNEH(reper &neh,double *abh)
    {
    double N[3],E[3],H[3];                  // [m]
    double p[3],xyzpos[3];
    const double da=1.567e-7;               // [rad] angular step ~ 1.0 m in lon direction
    const double dl=1.0;                    // [m] altitide step 1.0 m
    vector_copy(p,abh);
    // actual position
    WGS84toXYZ(xyzpos,abh);
    // NEH
    p[0]+=da; WGS84toXYZ(N,p); p[0]-=da;
    p[1]+=da; WGS84toXYZ(E,p); p[1]-=da;
    p[2]+=dl; WGS84toXYZ(H,p); p[2]-=dl;
    vector_sub(N,N,xyzpos);
    vector_sub(E,E,xyzpos);
    vector_sub(H,H,xyzpos);
    vector_one(N,N);
    vector_one(E,E);
    vector_one(H,H);
    neh._rep=1;
    neh._inv=0;
    // axis X
    neh.rep[ 0]=N[0];
    neh.rep[ 1]=N[1];
    neh.rep[ 2]=N[2];
    // axis Y
    neh.rep[ 4]=E[0];
    neh.rep[ 5]=E[1];
    neh.rep[ 6]=E[2];
    // axis Z
    neh.rep[ 8]=H[0];
    neh.rep[ 9]=H[1];
    neh.rep[10]=H[2];
    // gpos
    neh.rep[12]=xyzpos[0];
    neh.rep[13]=xyzpos[1];
    neh.rep[14]=xyzpos[2];
    neh.orto(1);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84toXYZ_posvel(double *xyzpos,double *xyzvel,double *abhpos,double *abhvel)
    {
    reper neh;
    WGS84toNEH(neh,abhpos);
    neh.gpos_get(xyzpos);
    neh.l2g_dir(xyzvel,abhvel);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84_m2rad(double &da,double &db,double *abh)
    {
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    double p[3],rr;
    WGS84toXYZ(p,abh);
    rr=(p[0]*p[0])+(p[1]*p[1]);
    da=divide(1.0,sqrt(rr));
    rr+=p[2]*p[2];
    db=divide(1.0,sqrt(rr));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XYZ_interpolate(double *pt,double *p0,double *p1,double t)
    {
    const double  mz=_earth_a/_earth_b;
    const double _mz=_earth_b/_earth_a;
    double p[3],r,r0,r1;
    // compute spherical radiuses of input points
    r0=sqrt((p0[0]*p0[0])+(p0[1]*p0[1])+(p0[2]*p0[2]*mz*mz));
    r1=sqrt((p1[0]*p1[0])+(p1[1]*p1[1])+(p1[2]*p1[2]*mz*mz));
    // linear interpolation
    r   = r0   +(r1   -r0   )*t;
    p[0]= p0[0]+(p1[0]-p0[0])*t;
    p[1]= p0[1]+(p1[1]-p0[1])*t;
    p[2]=(p0[2]+(p1[2]-p0[2])*t)*mz;
    // correct radius and rescale back
    r/=sqrt((p[0]*p[0])+(p[1]*p[1])+(p[2]*p[2]));
    pt[0]=p[0]*r;
    pt[1]=p[1]*r;
    pt[2]=p[2]*r*_mz;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However they require basic 3D vector math see here for equations:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Comment: I think you should write at some point that computing the difference quotient instead of the differential is an *approximation*. And there is an art to choosing the deltas (`da` and `dl`) right, as too large will affect directions while too small will drown signal in rounding errors. I don't see you taking differences of vectors, though. Nor dividing by the deltas. And I don't understand why you normalize the vectors. As these are still positions, you'd clamp them to a sphere. And after taking differences you'd loose the vital magnitude information.

Comment: what is number 2 about ? I'm sorry I don't get it. Where is Ux, Vx, Wx ? In capitals ? Should I calculate a new vector in step 2

Comment: @andre my bad it should be all the same I repaired it. It is hard to write code directly in editor ... when you do not see what are you typing properly

Comment: @MvG yes I know 1m is fine I think he use it for almost linear flight movement at speeds ~200km/h And yes I forget to substract +1 for that ... I was bombarded with comments at the time...

Comment: @Spektre You're not using x,y,z anywhere in the code

Comment: @andre of coarse using Cartesian speeds works only in Close by positions so do not expect using them in computations for time +2hod from `(x,y,z)` will give accurate results so your `_min_t` should be small enough so the traveled distance is not too big to curvature of Earth make huge difference

Comment: @Spektre: Normalize divides by norm, not by delta, as far as I can tell. So you'd have meter length units in all three directions, instead of “radian length” in the two angular directions. Just divide by the deltas instead of normalizing and you should be fine.

Comment: @MvG you are missing important info and that is that the spherical speed is in `[m/s]` instead of `[rad/s]` which is weird but it is as is (should be statet in OP). But I could be wrong too haven't had my cup of tea yet should be ready by now...

Comment: @andre added more precise conversions (I forgot to update them ...)

Answer (score 0):

Take the formula you use to convert positions from geographic to Cartesian coordinates. That's some vector p(λ,φ,h) ∈ ℝ³, i.e. you turn latitude, longitude and altitude into a three-element vector of x,y,z coordinates. Now compute the partial derivatives of this formula with respect to the three parameters. You will get three vectors, which should be orthogonal to one another. The derivative with respect to longitude λ should be pointing locally east, the one with respect to latitude φ pointing north, the one with respect to altitude h pointing up. Multiply these vectors with the velocities you have to obtain a Cartesian velocity vector.

Observe how the units match: the position is in meters, the first two derivatives are meters per degree, and the velocity would be degrees per second. Or something else, perhaps miles and radians.

All of this is fairly easy for the sphere. For the WGS84 ellipsoid the position formula is a bit more involved, and that complexity will carry through the computation.

Comment: can you show it in pseudo code please ? I'm not sure how to calculate the partial derivatives

Comment: @andre do not check answers if your problem is not solved (that goes also for mine answer in the first question) Check means you have solved the problem with help of this answer. Instead vote up or down if the answer is helpfull or not

Comment: @andre: No. I don't have the conversion between WGS84 and Cartesian at hand just now. Find that, then perhaps use Wolfram Alpha to compute derivatives if you don't want to do that by hand. That's what I'd do.

Comment: @andre: Fine. Use [this computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivatives+of+(a%2Fsqrt(1-%CE%B5*sin(%CE%B8)%5E2)%2Bh)*cos(%CE%B8)*sin(%CE%BB)) for first coordinate of vector in each of the three relevant directions. Adapt to compute the others.