# How to convert relative GPS coordinates to a "local custom" x, y, z coordinate?

Tags: gps, geometry, coordinates, wgs84

Let's say I know two persons are standing at **GPS** location `A` and `B`. `A` is looking at `B`.

I would like to know `B`'s (`x`, `y`, `z`) coordinates based on `A`, **where** the `+y` axis is the direction to `B` (since `A` is looking at B), `+z` is the vertically to the sky. (therefore `+x` is right-hand side of `A`)

I know how to convert a **GPS** coordinate to **UTM**, but in this case, a coordinate system rotation and translation seem needed. I am going to come up with a calculation, but before that, will there be some codes to look at?

I think this must be handled by many applications, but I could not find so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Convert booth points to 3D Cartesian**

   **GPS** suggest **WGS84** so see [How to convert a spherical velocity coordinates into cartesian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161714/2521214)
2. **Construct transform matrix with your desired axises**

   see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214). So you need 3 perpendicular unit vectors. The `Y` is view direction so

   ```
   Y = normalize(B-A);
   ```

   one of the axises will be most likely up vector so you can use approximation

   ```
   Z = normalize(A);
   ```

   and as origin you can use point `A` directly. Now just exploit cross product to create `X` perpendicular to both and make also `Y` perpendicular to `X` and `Z` (so up stays up). For more info see [Representing Points on a Circular Radar Math approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404784/2521214)
3. **Transfrom `B` to `B'` by that matrix**

   Again in the **QA** linked in **#1** is how to do it. It is simple matrix/vector multiplication.