# Compute outline of a complex shape efficiently

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, 3d, projection

I have many dots placed on the surface of a 3D sphere.

How can I compute the outline of the shape that encompass all the points at distance X of any of the dots ?

Here is an illustration to understand it better (in 2D for more clarity):

[image: 2D Illustration of the problem]

Every small red dot have their own "radius" property. If a point in the plane is inside the range "radius" of a red dot, it is represented in grey on the image.
What I am looking for is a list of lines allowing me to draw as precisely as possible the outline of the shape.

I need it to be really fast because there may be tens of thousands of those red dots, so I can't do some brut-force stuff.

I already have a k-d Tree representation of these points if this may help (k = 2 because points are stored as lat long values ).

[image: 3D illustration of the problem]

The animation above represents better what I need. You can see lots of blue "parts of spheres" of which I know the "centers" and the radiuses. And what I really need is the outline of this blue shape (there may be holes inside of it like in the first illustration)

Comment: Do you need a precise definition of the arcs making up the outline, or do you just need to draw it? If the latter, the easiest solution would probably be to just draw all the circles, then run an edge detection filter on it.

Comment: @Bergi Just drawing it would be fine. It’s just that even if I illustrated it with a 2D example, my goal is to achieve it on the surface of a 3D sphere so I don’t if that’s still possible with your solution. But I will try thanks.

Comment: The latter is what I need I guess. What info would you need ?

Comment: Thanks @Spektre, but wouldn't it distort the circles ? Like if I draw a simple circle on the 2D texture it won't appear as a circle when projected onto the globe, will it ?

Comment: @Paul. 2D circles on a sphere are circles, just tilted

Comment: @MadPhysicist 2D circles on a sphere projected on an equirectangular plane aren’t really circle, as shown by Tissot’s indicatrix.

Comment: @Paul. Then don't project them onto a plane until the end.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think the idea of Spektre requires that I do. Or maybe I didn’t understand it correctly…

Comment: @Paul. I can show you how to compute the circular arcs that make up the shape relatively efficiently. Turning them into line segments is pretty trivial after that, either before or after projection.

Comment: Is `r` identical for all the points? Do you realize why a KD tree with n==2 is fairly useless/misleading in this case?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would appreciate it very much !

Comment: Ok. You'll have to give me a minute. I refuse to pull a Lagrange and do something complex without diagrams only to regret it later.

Comment: If by r you refer to the distance to the center it is identical indeed. I thought 2 dimensions where required though to represent the two angles of a spherical coordinates system.

Comment: @Paul. Only if your tree implementation supports non-Euclidean metrics. Most of the tree implementations I've seen assume no wraparound and very specific distance computation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It can use any distance function I want so I use the haversine formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244156/discussion-between-paul-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you want correct output (no distortion) then I would go for ray caster and shaders... However not to get overwhelmed you by both C++ & GLSL at the same time I decided to do this in pure SW render (porting into GLSL is easy from that)...

It works like this:

1. **loop through "all" pixels of screen**

   You can use expected BBOX of your sphere clipped by screen to improve speed...
2. **cast a ray from camera focus into actual screen pixel**
3. **compute intersection between ray and sphere**

   You can use this:

   - [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214)
4. **compute SDF (Signed Distance Function) between hit surface point and your PCL**

   for that you need to convert your spherical coordinates into Cartesian. In case you use ellipsoid instead of sphere see:

   - [WGS84 conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41123777/2521214)
5. **color your pixel based on result of SDF**

   so if distance is positive it means pixel is outside region, If its zero you are on edge and if it is negative you inside ...

**Here small simple C++/VCL example for this using WGS84:**

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include "GLSL_math.h"
#include "performance.h"
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// poins
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct _pnt
    {
    float lat,lon,r;
    vec3 p;             // temp for computed (x,y,z) position
    };
const int pnts=100;
_pnt pnt[pnts];
void pnt_init()
    {
    int i;
    Randomize();
    for (i=0;i<pnts;i++)
        {
        pnt[i].lon=(2.0*M_PI*Random())           ;
        pnt[i].lat=(    M_PI*Random())-(0.5*M_PI);
        pnt[i].r=1000000.0;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// WGS84 constants
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const float _WGS84_a=6378137.00000;   // [m] WGS84 equator radius
const float _WGS84_b=6356752.31414;   // [m] WGS84 epolar radius
const float _WGS84_e=8.1819190842622e-2; //  WGS84 eccentricity
const float _WGS84_aa=_WGS84_a*_WGS84_a;
const float _WGS84_bb=_WGS84_b*_WGS84_b;
const float _WGS84_ee=_WGS84_e*_WGS84_e;
const vec3 _WGS84_rr(1.0/_WGS84_aa,1.0/_WGS84_aa,1.0/_WGS84_bb);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// return if intersection occur and if yes set l as ray length to intersection
bool WGS84_ray_intersection(vec3 p0,vec3 dp,float &l)
    {
    vec3 r;
    float a,b,c,d,l0,l1;
    // init solver
    l=-1.0;
    r=_WGS84_rr;    // where r.x is elipsoid rx^-2, r.y = ry^-2 and r.z=rz^-2
    // quadratic equation a.l.l+b.l+c=0; l0,l1=?;
    a=(dp.x*dp.x*r.x)
     +(dp.y*dp.y*r.y)
     +(dp.z*dp.z*r.z);
    b=(p0.x*dp.x*r.x)
     +(p0.y*dp.y*r.y)
     +(p0.z*dp.z*r.z); b*=2.0;
    c=(p0.x*p0.x*r.x)
     +(p0.y*p0.y*r.y)
     +(p0.z*p0.z*r.z)-1.0;
    // discriminant d=sqrt(b.b-4.a.c)
    d=((b*b)-(4.0*a*c));
    if (d<0.0) return false;
    d=sqrt(d);
    // standard solution l0,l1=(-b +/- d)/2.a
    a*=2.0;
    l0=(-b+d)/a;
    l1=(-b-d)/a;
    // alternative solution q=-0.5*(b+sign(b).d) l0=q/a; l1=c/q; (should be more accurate sometimes)
//  if (b<0.0) d=-d; d=-0.5*(b+d);
//  l0=d/a;
//  l1=c/d;
    // sort l0,l1 asc
    if (fabs(l0)>fabs(l1)) { a=l0; l0=l1; l1=a; }
    if (l0<0.0)            { a=l0; l0=l1; l1=a; }
    if (l0<0.0) return false;
    // return first hit l0, and ignore second l1
    l=l0;
    return true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XYZtoWGS84(float &lon,float &lat,float &alt,float x,float y,float z)
    {
    int i;
    float  a,b,h,l,n,db,s;
    a=atan2(y,x);
    l=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
    // estimate lat
    b=atan2(z,(1.0-_WGS84_ee)*l);
    // iterate to improve accuracy
    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
        s=sin(b); db=b;
        n=_WGS84_a/sqrt(1.0-(_WGS84_ee*s*s));
        h=(l/cos(b))-n;
        b=atan2(z,(1.0-divide(_WGS84_ee*n,n+h))*l);
        db=fabs(db-b);
        if (db<1e-12) break;
        }
    if (b>0.5*M_PI) b-=2.0*M_PI;
    lon=a;
    lat=b;
    alt=h;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84toXYZ(float &x,float &y,float &z,float lon,float lat,float alt) // [rad,rad,m] -> [m,m,m]
    {
    float  a,b,h,l,c,s;
    a=lon;
    b=lat;
    h=alt;
    c=cos(b);
    s=sin(b);
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    l=_WGS84_a/sqrt(1.0-(_WGS84_ee*s*s));
    x=(l+h)*c*cos(a);
    y=(l+h)*c*sin(a);
    z=(((1.0-_WGS84_ee)*l)+h)*s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84_draw(float yaw)
    {
    // my Direct Pixel access to backbufer Main->bmp
    int **Pixels=Main->pyx;                     // Pixels[y][x]
    int   xs=Main->xs;                          // resolution
    int   ys=Main->ys;
    float xs2=0.5*float(xs);                    // half resolution (center of screen)
    float ys2=0.5*float(ys);
    // variables
    int sx,sy;                                  // pixel coordinate
    vec3 O,X,Y,Z;                               // camera location and orientation
    float focal_length;                         // camera focal length
    vec3 p0,dp;                                 // ray
    vec3 p;                                     // WGS84 surface point
    float l,ll;                                 // ray length
    int i;
    DWORD c=0x00204080;
    // int camera
    l=3.0*_WGS84_a;                             // some distance so WGS84 is visible
    focal_length=(0.5*float(xs))/tan(30.0*M_PI/180.0);  // xs,FOVx/2 -> focal_length
    O=vec3(-l*cos(yaw),0.0,-l*sin(yaw));        // origin
    X=vec3(  -sin(yaw),0.0,  +cos(yaw));        // right
    Y=vec3(        0.0,1.0,        0.0);        // up
    Z=vec3(  +cos(yaw),0.0,  +sin(yaw));        // forward
    // render
    p0=O;                                       // ray origin is at camera focus
    // precompute cartesian position for all pnt[]
    for (i=0;i<pnts;i++)
        {
        float x,y,z;
        WGS84toXYZ(x,y,z,pnt[i].lon,pnt[i].lat,0.0);
        pnt[i].p=vec3(x,y,z);
        }
    // render screen (pixel by pixel)
    for (sx=0;sx<xs;sx++)
     for (sy=0;sy<ys;sy++)
        {
        p=vec3(sx,sy,focal_length);             // compute ray direction (in camera local coordinates)
        p.x-=xs2;                               // shift (0,0) to center of screen
        p.y-=ys2;
        dp.x=dot(p,X);                          // convert to world global ones
        dp.y=dot(p,Y);
        dp.z=dot(p,Z);
        dp=normalize(dp);
        if (WGS84_ray_intersection(p0,dp,l))    // is ray hitting the WGS84 ?
            {
            p=p0+l*dp;                          // surface point hit
            // SDF to points
            l=1e100;
            for (i=0;i<pnts;i++)
                {
                ll=length(p-pnt[i].p)-pnt[i].r;
                if (l>ll) l=ll;
                }
                 if (l>     0.0) c=0x00204080;  // outside
            else if (l>-50000.0) c=0x00808000;  // edge (50km width)
            else                 c=0x00802020;  // inside
            Pixels[sy][sx]=c;                   // render pixel
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    tbeg(); // start timemeasurement
    static float yaw=0.0; yaw=fmod(yaw+0.1,2.0*M_PI);
    WGS84_draw(yaw);
    tend(); // stop timemeasurement

    // just render measured time
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Color=clYellow;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
    bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(5,5,tstr());
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;

    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    pyx=NULL;
    pnt_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;  xs2=xs>>1;
    ys=ClientHeight; ys2=ys>>1;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    if (pyx) delete pyx;
    pyx=new int*[ys];
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(int*) bmp->ScanLine[y];
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just ignore the VCL stuff and exchange the rendering of pixels to your environment. Note pixel access is usually very slow so I render to bitmap instead accessing it as pointer to 32 bit unsigned ints and when whole stuff is done I render the bitmap... For more info about the stuff see:

- [gfx rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)

The only important stuff is the `WGS84_draw` and sub-functions it is using.

The only non standard lib I used is my [GLSL_math.h](https://ulozto.net/tamhle/Lac6wsTA65Ni#!ZJD0MwR2AJR0ZmR5LJAyZwHlLJH1MJyBAGL0I3MvJKDlF2L3LD==) which mimics GLSL math and can be done with any vector lib like GLM ...

**Here preview:**

[image: preview]
[image: animation]

As you can see no distortions are present...

In case you do not want to ray cast like this then you have to convert your points into triangulated polygons covering their radius and sphere curvature in Cartesian and render them like this:

1. Render all circles with edge color
2. Render all circles with inside color but with radius decreased by edge width

In case you do not want the inside its enough to have just the edges polygons instead and render once ...

**[Edit1] I managed to get shader version of this working:**

**CPU side code:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include "GLSL_math.h"
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// WGS84 constants
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const float _WGS84_a=6378137.00000;   // [m] WGS84 equator radius
const float _WGS84_b=6356752.31414;   // [m] WGS84 epolar radius
const float _WGS84_e=8.1819190842622e-2; //  WGS84 eccentricity
const float _WGS84_aa=_WGS84_a*_WGS84_a;
const float _WGS84_bb=_WGS84_b*_WGS84_b;
const float _WGS84_ee=_WGS84_e*_WGS84_e;
const vec3 _WGS84_rr(1.0/_WGS84_aa,1.0/_WGS84_aa,1.0/_WGS84_bb);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XYZtoWGS84(float &lon,float &lat,float &alt,vec3 p)
    {
    int i;
    float  a,b,h,l,n,db,s;
    a=atan2(p.y,p.x);
    l=sqrt((p.x*p.x)+(p.y*p.y));
    // estimate lat
    b=atan2(p.z,(1.0-_WGS84_ee)*l);
    // iterate to improve accuracy
    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
        s=sin(b); db=b;
        n=_WGS84_a/sqrt(1.0-(_WGS84_ee*s*s));
        h=(l/cos(b))-n;
        b=atan2(p.z,(1.0-divide(_WGS84_ee*n,n+h))*l);
        db=fabs(db-b);
        if (db<1e-12) break;
        }
    if (b>0.5*M_PI) b-=2.0*M_PI;
    lon=a;
    lat=b;
    alt=h;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WGS84toXYZ(float &x,float &y,float &z,float lon,float lat,float alt) // [rad,rad,m] -> [m,m,m]
    {
    float  a,b,h,l,c,s;
    a=lon;
    b=lat;
    h=alt;
    c=cos(b);
    s=sin(b);
    // WGS84 from eccentricity
    l=_WGS84_a/sqrt(1.0-(_WGS84_ee*s*s));
    x=(l+h)*c*cos(a);
    y=(l+h)*c*sin(a);
    z=(((1.0-_WGS84_ee)*l)+h)*s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// points
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int pnts=1000;
struct _pnt{ float x,y,z,r; };
_pnt pnt[pnts];
void pnt_init()
    {
    int i;
    Randomize();
    for (i=0;i<pnts;i++)
        {
        float lat,lon,r,x,y,z;
        lon=(2.0*M_PI*Random())           ;
        lat=(    M_PI*Random())-(0.5*M_PI);
        r=250000.0+250000.0*Random();
        WGS84toXYZ(x,y,z,lon,lat,0.0);
        pnt[i].x=x;
        pnt[i].y=y;
        pnt[i].z=z;
        pnt[i].r=r;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    int i;

    // int camera
    static float yaw=0.0; yaw=fmod(yaw+0.05,2.0*M_PI);
    float l=3.0*_WGS84_a;                                   // some distance so WGS84 is visible
    float focal_length=(1.0)/tan(30.0*M_PI/180.0);          // xs,FOVx/2 -> focal_length
    float tm_eye[16];

//  yaw=90.0*M_PI/180.0;

    // right
    tm_eye[ 0]=-sin(yaw);
    tm_eye[ 1]=0.0;
    tm_eye[ 2]=+cos(yaw);
    tm_eye[ 3]=0.0;
    // up
    tm_eye[ 4]=0.0;
    tm_eye[ 5]=1.0;
    tm_eye[ 6]=0.0;
    tm_eye[ 7]=0.0;
    // forward
    tm_eye[ 8]=+cos(yaw);
    tm_eye[ 9]=0.0;
    tm_eye[10]=+sin(yaw);
    tm_eye[11]=0.0;
    // origin
    tm_eye[12]=-l*cos(yaw);
    tm_eye[13]=0.0;
    tm_eye[14]=-l*sin(yaw);
    tm_eye[15]=0.0;

//  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // GL render
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glUseProgram(prog_id);
    i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"pnts"        ); glUniform1i(i,pnts);
    i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"pnt"         ); glUniform4fv(i,pnts,(float*)(pnt));
    i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"_WGS84_rr"   ); glUniform3fv(i,1,_WGS84_rr.dat);
    i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"width");        glUniform1f(i,50000.0);
    i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"focal_length"); glUniform1f(i,focal_length);
    i=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"tm_eye"      ); glUniformMatrix4fv(i,1,false,tm_eye);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
    glVertex2f(-1.0,+1.0);
    glVertex2f(+1.0,+1.0);
    glVertex2f(+1.0,-1.0);
    glEnd();
    glUseProgram(0);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);
    int hnd,siz; char vertex[4096],geometry[4096],fragment[4096];
    hnd=FileOpen("WGS84_region.glsl_vert",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,vertex  ,siz); vertex  [siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    hnd=FileOpen("WGS84_region.glsl_frag",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,fragment,siz); fragment[siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    glsl_init(vertex,NULL,fragment);
    mm_log->Text=glsl_log;
    pnt_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_exit();
    glsl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth-mm_log->Width,ClientHeight);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Vertex:**

```cpp
// Vertex
#version 400 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;   // control points (QUADS)

uniform mat4 tm_eye;                // camera
uniform float focal_length;

out vec3 ray_p0;                    // ray origin
out vec3 ray_dp;                    // ray direction

void main()
    {
    vec3 p;
    ray_p0=tm_eye[3].xyz;
    ray_dp=normalize((tm_eye*vec4(pos,focal_length,0.0)).xyz);
    gl_Position=vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Fragment
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 400 core

uniform int pnts;       // PCL size
uniform vec4 pnt[1000]; // PCL (x,y,z,r) limit on my GPU is 1021
uniform vec3 _WGS84_rr; // elipsoid rr.x = rx^-2, rr.y = ry^-2, rr.z=rz^-2
uniform float width;    // region edge width

in vec3 ray_p0;         // ray origin
in vec3 ray_dp;         // ray direction

out vec4 col;           // output color
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// return if intersection occur and if yes set l as ray length to intersection
float ray_l=1e30; // return value
bool WGS84_ray_intersection(vec3 p0,vec3 dp)
    {
    vec3 r;
    float a,b,c,d,l0,l1;
    // init solver
    ray_l=-1.0;
    r=_WGS84_rr;    // where r.x is elipsoid rx^-2, r.y = ry^-2 and r.z=rz^-2
    // quadratic equation a.l.l+b.l+c=0; l0,l1=?;
    a=(dp.x*dp.x*r.x)
     +(dp.y*dp.y*r.y)
     +(dp.z*dp.z*r.z);
    b=(p0.x*dp.x*r.x)
     +(p0.y*dp.y*r.y)
     +(p0.z*dp.z*r.z); b*=2.0;
    c=(p0.x*p0.x*r.x)
     +(p0.y*p0.y*r.y)
     +(p0.z*p0.z*r.z)-1.0;
    // discriminant d=sqrt(b.b-4.a.c)
    d=((b*b)-(4.0*a*c));
    if (d<0.0) return false;
    d=sqrt(d);
    // standard solution l0,l1=(-b +/- d)/2.a
    a*=2.0;
    l0=(-b+d)/a;
    l1=(-b-d)/a;
    // alternative solution q=-0.5*(b+sign(b).d) l0=q/a; l1=c/q; (should be more accurate sometimes)
//  if (b<0.0) d=-d; d=-0.5*(b+d);
//  l0=d/a;
//  l1=c/d;
    // sort l0,l1 asc
    if (abs(l0)>abs(l1)) { a=l0; l0=l1; l1=a; }
    if (l0<0.0)          { a=l0; l0=l1; l1=a; }
    if (l0<0.0) return false;
    // return first hit l0, and ignore second l1
    ray_l=l0;
    return true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    int i;
    vec3 p,c;
    float l,ll;
    if (!WGS84_ray_intersection(ray_p0,ray_dp)) discard;// is ray hitting the WGS84 ?
    p=ray_p0+ray_l*ray_dp;                              // surface point hit
    // SDF to points
    l=1e30;
    for (i=0;i<pnts;i++)
        {
        ll=length(p-pnt[i].xyz)-pnt[i].w;
        if (l>ll) l=ll;
        }
         if (l>   0.0) c=vec3(0.1,0.3,0.5); // outside
    else if (l>-width) c=vec3(0.1,0.8,0.9); // edge
    else               c=vec3(0.3,0.3,0.3); // inside
    col=vec4(c,1.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And preview (1000 points):**

[image: Shader preview]

However I can not pass more than 1021 points due my gfx implementation limitation so if you want more you have to use textures like I mentioned before (do nto forget to use non clamping pixelformat like `GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB` ...

Speed and resolution does not seem to be any issue on my setup (nVidia
GTX 550 Ti).

Also note that above example does not contain any aspect ratio correction yet ...