# How to find amplitude and frequency of sine wave from 20 samples?

Tags: c, algorithm, signals, microcontroller, trigonometry

I have signal with these parameters: 1kHz frequency, 1Vpp.
I'm trying to find the best algorithm to calculate the signal's amplitude and frequency from **20** samples. I will try to implement this algorithm in C language (on my microcontroller). 
I've estimated the sampling frequency to 2.5kHz Pic of sampled sine wave:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Your best choice seems DCT (discrete cosine transform). As your sample count is low it could be nicely optimized. One drawback will be limited accuracy (for freq) because of low sample count and low sampling rate.

Comment: @Anty could you elaborate on this a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **rough estimate**

   simply find 2 x (time) positions where y (amplitude) is the same and slope is also in same direction (rise/decline). Their distance `T` is the period.

   [image: period]

   You can increase the precision by handling your data as a polyline (linear or higher interpolation).

   Now amplitude is just `A = (max(value)-min(value))/2`.

   You can also estimate the initial phase `t0` which is x  position where data is crossing offset value and offset `y0 = 0.5*(max(value)+min(value))` Beware `y0` might be anything not just zero ...

   So your sinwave is done like:

   ```
   y(t) = y0 + 0.5*A*sin((t-t0)*2.0*M_PI/T)
   ```
2. **precision**

   if you need much better precision then just fit a sinwave  through your points. As you got already the initial estimates then this is not so slow as a blind fit.  Here an example:

   - [Trying to fit a sine function to phased light curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41208993/2521214)

Comment: `A = (max - min)/2`

Comment: @Zaz yes for un-biased sin wave you're right I edited the answer ... In different circumstances it depends on the definition/meaning of amplitude for the task ahead