# Write code on Python: Restore the sinusoid from noisy measurements

Tags: python, math

I need to calculate the plane coordinates (x,y). There is a trajectory of change and it is necessary to calculate the subsequent coordinates. There is an approximate formula for changing coordinates, it depends on two coefficients `k1` and `k2` and random noise:

```
x = k2cos(k1t) + noise
y = k1sin(k2t) + noise
```

At the input is given a list of 1000 pairs of coordinates x y first thousand seconds (from 0 to 999):

```
[(0.8990863593574939, 8.475387292276096e-07), (0.8089593833113505, 0. 3534820061950688), (0.5566465706027002, 0.4399620826711653), (0.19273411906364982, 0.19411748737324), (-0. 20981822525965102, -0.19835273653070376), (-0.5703058016775612, -0.44099688186601116), (-0.8164537877967621, -0. 35053466833726243), (-0.8989145629777989, 0.004703700279075586), … (-0.801155143314037, 0. 35638955826565816), (-0.5427749453575453, 0.43887713883486584), (-0.17557562076019273, 0.18985994842390025), (0. 22682425709951057, -0.20256735021079741), (0.5837487993279974, -0.4419853288796921), (0.8236405373374047, -0. 3475501356746985), (0.8984026035824828, 0.009406628459256976), (0.7930484451922395, 0.3592589441057791)]
```

In response, an array of 1000 pairs for the second thousand seconds (from 1000 to 1999) is expected, example:

```
[(0.8990863593574939, 8.475387292276096e-07), (0. 8089593833113505, 0.3534820061950688), (0.5566465706027002, 0.4399620826711653), (0.19273411906364982, 0. 19411748737324), (-0.20981822525965102, -0.19835273653070376), (-0.5703058016775612, -0.44099688186601116), (-0. 8164537877967621, -0.35053466833726243), (-0.8989145629777989, 0.004703700279075586), … (-0.801155143314037, 0. 35638955826565816), (-0.5427749453575453, 0.43887713883486584), (-0.17557562076019273, 0.18985994842390025), (0. 22682425709951057, -0.20256735021079741), (0.5837487993279974, -0.4419853288796921), (0.8236405373374047, -0. 3475501356746985), (0.8984026035824828, 0.009406628459256976), (0.7930484451922395, 0.3592589441057791)]
```

Comment: so fit `k1,k2` until the abs difference between data and function (without noise) is minimal. `|(k2*cos(k2*t),k1*sin(k1*t)) - data[t]|` In case you know more about the noise you can narrow down the `k1,k2` search from input data properties like avg, trend, frequency ... for more info see [Trying to fit a sine function to phased light curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41208993/2521214)

Comment: When I tried it in C++ your sample data lead to `k1=0.45158, k2=0.899080` it might be possible to approximately determine the `k1,k2` directly form the frequency of `x` and `y` signal. So find two consequent zero crossings in `x` and the number of samples coresponds to `k1*samples = 6.28`  the same goes for `y`  and `k2`. After this just fit nearby these values

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts, I will try it.

Comment: btw the `-min` and `+max` values in `x` and `y` are the `k2,k1` ... but you have 1 sec interval so you are missing the peaks ... so k1,k2 will be slightly higher ...