# 2d Mountainy Terrain

Tags: math, trigonometry, terrain

Hi i am new on strackoverflow, could anyone help me with 2d Terrain trigonometry algorithm, how to achieve something like in screenshot?

[image]

[this tutorial](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/07/14/create-a-terrain-like-the-one-in-tiny-wings-with-flash-and-box2d/) helps me a lot but still can't figure out how to create mountain terrain

My attempt evolved to this:

```
Vector (v0.x + t * length, center + amplitude * Mathf.Cos (angle * t));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: here: Vector (v0.x + t * length, center + amplitude * Mathf.Cos (angle * t));

Comment: That first link seems to be dead.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hjx84r

Comment: Can you specify the *something like* part and what part you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like chain so:

1. **generate `n` random height points**

   just the peaks covering your screen or map or whatever.
2. **compute chain between neighbors**

   the chain length should be bigger then the distance between points. For the math see:

   - [Wiki: Catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary)

   [image: equation]

   the equation image was taken from the Wiki page linked.

Comment: Thanks @Spektre i definitely try that

Comment: @wrRios the problem is the computation of `a` is a bit complicated but you can try this [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214) or approximate/fake the curve with `y=c0+c1*(x-x0)^2`