# Numerical methods to solve function with restricted domain

Tags: algorithm, physics, numerical-methods

Methods to solve(root finding) the function with the restricted domain.

Suppose to solve the function

```
$sin^{-1}(\sqrt{E_n/V}) +a*\sqrt{2mE_n/h^2}=n*\pi$
```

where

```
$E_n,V,a,m,h n$ were all positive.
```

I tried to use Newton-Raphson Method to solve it where I realized that the input of those function must be positive thus from divergence

```
$iterate E_{n}(i+1)$
```

might be negative, thus produce a false result and stop the iteration.

The only solution I could found was thorough trust zone methods as

```
 $E_n<=V$
```

was guaranteed by the function's physical meaning. However, it took much longer time.

Was there a way to use some fast computation like Newton-Raphson Method for this expression.

Comment: You could try expressing each of the positive variables as squares of unconstrained variables. (`F^2_n` instead of `E_n`, `W^2` instead of `V`, etc.)

Comment: You could also use the secant method (or a hybrid NR), which requires an initial range. Conveniently `arcsin` requires an argument in the range `[-1, 1]`, and the sign requirement for `E` reduces this to `[0, 1]`.

Comment: when I am too lazy to do the math or unable or nothing else works for such cases I use this [How approximation search works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214) the main trick is to select the bounds and steps but you already have the bounds ...

Comment: I guess you're solving equation for E and rest are constant parameters. Then you can use Ridders method which converges quadratically or revert to bisection if Newton iteration takes you out of root bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary from the comments to close the topic.

If the input of the funciton was restricted to, i.e.>0.

1. We could set m^2_n instead of x as squares of unconstrained variables – Ted Hopp
2. Secant method – meowgoesthedog
3. Ridders' method. - Shimuuar
4. Trust zone methods.