# Solution Diophantine equation with n variable with ranges

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-algebra, linear-programming

During Software designing our team come across the following problem:
we have linear Diophantine equation with n variables with each variable have positive permissible range or allowed range.

```
a1x1+a2x2+....+anxn = b
known parameters:
a1,a2,...,an and b
unknown parameter x1,x2,....,xn
but we know that 
x1 belongs to range [l1,r1]
x2 belongs to range [l2,r2]
.
.
.
xn belongs to range [ln,rn]
0<li<ri
ai>0
b>0
```

and we need to find values of all xi in above equation(may be float or integer).
I have come across lot of solution online one of them [CP-algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/linear-diophantine-equation.html) and another one is reduce problem [Coin change problem of DP](https://www.techiedelight.com/total-possible-solutions-linear-equation-k-variables/).
But I am thinking there must be better algorithm to this problem.

Comment: If the `a_i` are all positive, then reducing to the coin change problem seems like the correct approach.

Comment: you can even use fitting ... btw is this on integers or floats? are the ranges positive or non negative  only? what are the limits of `m=max(r(i)-l(i))`  and `n` ... as brute force solution is `O(m^n)` ... fitting like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36163846/2521214) might convert this into `O((log(m))^n)`

Comment: Thanks guys for comment this really help me to solve the problem