# Algorithm to find desired direction with minimum amount of iterations

Tags: algorithm, 3d, vectormath

There's three components to this problem:

1. A three dimensional vector **A**.
2. A "smooth" function **F**.
3. A desired vector **B** (also three dimensional).

We want to find a vector **A** that when put through **F** will produce the vector **B**.

```
F(A) = B
```

**F** can be anything that somehow transforms or distorts **A** in some manner. The point is that we want to iteratively call **F(A)** until **B** is produced.

The question is:

How can we do this, but with the least amount of calls to **F** before finding a vector that equals **B** (within a reasonable threshold)?

Comment: If function F is "smooth", you can define "closeness" measure for vectors and try gradient descent or some another kind of iterative optimization algorithm. This is "un-informed search", so it is worth to generate some random vectors at first to get initial approximation

Comment: 1. brute force with least amount of iterations is not brute force at all.... 2. if `F()` is also monotonic you can use binary search if not you need different kind of search like CCD or [approximation search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214) 3. the part of your post after `F(A) = B` describes entirely different problem (F is unknown) than before it (A is unknown) or its just my bad English? can you clarify ... If you want to construct `F` so it takes any `A` and converges to selected `B` ? that should be relatively easy to do.

Comment: for example by decomposing it to scale and rotation change between `A,B` and interpolate it with some `n` steps. Also are we talking about integer, float or fixed point? how many bits, how many iterations,what range of values ..

Comment: In this particular case, F is a matrix transformation that is missing an inverse (think linear blend skinning).

You are correct, brute force was poor wording.

Comment: @quano maybe you should add a sample input (with the F) ... also you still did not clear what is unknown `F` or `A` ? as half of your post suggest `A` and the other `F`

Comment: @Spektre A is unknown. F and B are known.

Comment: @quano can you share actual example of `F,B` ... linear blend skinning is not a good choice as it has much more than just 1x3D vector input ... also how many steps of Applying `F` on `A` to produce `B` ?  it is fixed constant `n>=1` or stop once the result has converged ? ...

Comment: LBS does have more inputs, but only **A** would have to change to try and find **B** (the skinning weights and bone transformation would be fixed).

How many steps? As few steps as possible. It doesn't need to be fixed. Loop can break when a value within threshold has been reached.

Comment: @quano Well if LBS is the `F()` then its not just a matrix operation as you suggested... and without actual example i am not confident to create an answer that might not be what you looking for because it works but not for your exact `F` case ...

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that what you call "smooth" is tantamount to being differentiable.
Since the concept of smoothness only makes sense in the rational / real numbers, I will also assume that you are solving a floating point-based problem.

In this case, I would formulate the problem as a nonlinear programming problem. i.e. minimizing the squared norm of the difference between f(A) and B, given by

```
(F(A)_1 -B_1)² + (F(A)_2 - B_2)² + (F(A)_3 - B_3)²
```

It should be clear that this expression is zero if and only if f(A) = B and positive otherwise. Therefore you would want to minimize it.

As an example, you could use the solvers built into the `scipy` optimization suite (available for python):

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Example function
f = lambda x : [x[0] + 1, x[2], 2*x[1]]

# Optimization objective
fsq = lambda x : sum(v*v for v in f(x))

# Initial guess
x0 = [0,0,0]

res = minimize(fsq, x0, tol=1e-6)

# res.x is the solution, in this case
# array([-1.00000000e+00,  2.49999999e+00, -5.84117172e-09])
```

A binary search (as pointed out above) only works if the function is 1-d, which is *not* the case here. You can try out different optimization methods by adding the `method="name"` to the call to `minimize`, see the [API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). It is not always clear which method works best for your problem without knowing more about the nature of your function. As a rule of thumb, the more information you give to the solver, the better. If you can compute the derivative of `F` explicitly, passing it to the solver will help reduce the number of required evaluations. If `F` has a Hessian (i.e., if it is twice differentiable), providing the Hessian will help as well.

As an alternative, you can use the `least_squares` function on `F` directly via `res = least_squares(f, x0)`. This could be faster since the solver can take care of the fact that you are solving a least squares problem rather than a generic optimization problem.

From a more general standpoint, the problem of restoring the function arguments producing a given value is called an [Inverse Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem#General_statement_of_the_inverse_problem). These problems have been *extensively* studied.

Comment: in case of convergence of repeated application of `A=F(A)` into `B` as OP described your solution would most likely not work ...

Answer (score 2):

Provided that F(A)=B,  F,B are known and A remains unknown, you can start with a simple gradient search:

```
F(A)~= F(C) + F'(C)*(A-C)~=B
```

where `F'(C)` is the gradient of F() evaluated in point C. I'm assuming you can calculate this gradient analytically for now.

So, you can choose a point C that you estimate it is not very far from the solution and iterate by:

```
C= Co;
While(true)
{
   Ai = inverse(F'(C))*(B-F(C)) + C;
   convergence = Abs(Ai-C);
   C=Ai;

   if(convergence<someThreshold)
      break;
}
```

if the gradient of F() cannot be calculated analytically, you can estimate it. Let `Ei, i=1:3` be the ortonormal vectors, then

```
   Fi'(C) = (F(C+Ei*d) - F(C-Ei*d))/(2*d);
   F'(C) = [F1'(C) | F2'(C) | F3'(C)];
```

and `d` can be chosen as fixed or as a function of the convergence value.

These algorithms suffer from the problem of local maxima, null gradient areas, etc., so in order for it to work, the start point (Co) must be not very far from the solution where the function F() behaves monotonically

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you can try a metaheuristic approach for this.
[Genetic algorithm (GA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) might be the best suite for this.
you can initiate a number of A vector to init a population, and use GA to make evolution on your population, so you will have better generation in which they have better vectors that F(Ax) closer to B.
Your fitness function can be a simple function that compare F(Ai) to B
You can choose how to mutate your population by each generation.

A simple example about GA can be found here [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3)