# Moving a bone along a spline curve

Tags: math, graphics, computational-geometry, spline, inverse-kinematics

I have a B-spline curve that I want a rigid bone to move along, and I want to calculate the inverse kinematics of one end of the bone when I move the other end. Both ends of the bone should lie on the curve, and the length of the bone should stay consistent. I have the necessary functions to convert B-spline curve into other parametric curves like Bézier curves. How should I go about tackling this problem?

Example scenario:

Initially spline with bone:

[image: spline with bone]

After some time spline with bone moved:

[image: spline with bone moved]

These images are done with manually moving the points, so the bone length is not consistent. However for the calculated result it should be.

Currently what I am looking at is first pin down the head of the bone, then draw a circle centered at the head with radius of the bone length, and find intersections between the circle and the spline. I found chapter 7.3 of [Computer Aided Geometric Design by T. W. Sederberg](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=facpub) describing intersection between parametric curve and implicit curves, which seems to fit my needs, but I'm unsure how to apply it to my problem, and how to efficiently solve for the polynomial roots.

Context: I am making a 2D vector animation engine for my own use. The front end is JavaScript and html5 canvas in a browser, and the calculation part is done in Rust compiled into WASM.

Comment: It occurs to me that the distance between points f(u) and f(v) is a function of two variables, where f is a parametrization of the spline function (i.e. f(u) traces out the spline as u goes from some starting value to some ending value), and you want to follow a contour of constant value (with the constant being the length of the bone). Maybe you can adapt a contour-following algorithm to your problem.

Comment: You could use a binary chop-like method to find v such that |f(u) - f(v)| = bone-length. There might not always be a solution, or there could be multiple solutions, so you'd have to decide what to do about that.

Comment: first point is just `BEZIER(t)` where `t` is your parameter of movement in range `t = <0,1>`. the second point is `BEZIER(t+dt)` where `dt` can be fitted with for example this  [Approximation search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163847/2521214). To ease up the search you might compute approximate BEZIER curve length and start search the dt around `dt=bone_length/BEZIER_length` but the approx search do not really need it ...